# Leading constraint with multiplier not working

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a button with leading and trailing constraints set as below. Here I have set the constants to 0 and gave a multiplier to superview.

The trailing constraint is working properly but not the leading constraint.

Tried the same with storyboard as well but there also leading multiplier is not working.

```
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1.2, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: button, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1.2, constant: 0))
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

How can I set the leading constraint with multiplier to superview

Comment: What do you expect to multiply if you don't have anything to multiply?

Comment: @Desdenova `multiplier` is applied to the attribute of the `item`, not to the `constant`. The code is correct.

Comment: @Desdenova I have given multiplier: 1.2 for both the constraints

Comment: @pradeep what is the `leading` value of `button`?

Comment: @mag_zbc No it isn’t correct. Let me rephrase, how would you plan to multiply leading constraint?

Comment: @Desdenova normally?.. If `button.leading` is i.e. 100, then the result constraint would be `120`. `view.leading = button.leading * multiplier + constant`

Comment: @mag_zbc see, thats the constant you are multiplying

Comment: @Desdenova and where did he post that `button.leading` equals `0`? You're not multiplying constant, you are multiplying `button.leading`, constant is added at the very end.

Comment: @pradeep Basically you want 10% padding left and right for your button? Is it your intent?

Comment: @mag_zbc leading against which view?. As I am trying to set the leading against the superview as shown in the question

Comment: @shota I am trying to give leading and trailing constraints by a mulitplier(%) so it looks at same ratio for all the screensizes and orientations

Comment: @pradeep what do you think to make your button equal width to your view and then use multiplier? In your example code you are setting button's leading and trailing to 0, so you can set button's width to be equal to view's width multiplied by 0.8. I think i would give you desired result.

Comment: @shota Thanks It will work. I just want to know if it is possible with the scenario mentioned above

Answer (score 3):

**1-**

```
firsItem(view)Leading = secondItem(button)Leading * 1.2 + constant
```

Equal

```
0 = secondItem(button)Leading * 1.2 + 0
```

so `secondItem(button)Leading` = 0

**2-**

```
firsItem(view)Trailing = secondItem(button)Trailing * 1.2 + constant
```

Equal

```
viewWidth = secondItem(button)Trailing * 1.2 + 0
```

so `secondItem(button)Trailing` = viewWidth / 1.2

Comment: Where can we set the button.leading? How is the button.trailing is working as I am not setting it as well?

Comment: If you didn't set a constraint for `button.leading` anchor, then it's probably `0`, as by default autoresizing masks are translated to constraints. What's the `frame` you are setting for your `button`?

Comment: @mag_zbc frame is (0, 80, 400, 40). and the width is going to change based on the leading and trailing constrains.

Comment: Then it's obvious - `button.leading` is `0`

Comment: @mag_zbc and Sh_Khan So how can we explicitly set the button.leading before setting multiplier.

Comment: you need to only set the constant value in your constraints for leading -20 , for trailing 20 , and set multiplier to 1 , so you'll get a button with 20 its from both sides

Comment: @Sh_Khan That means giving fixed constant. So is it not possible to give a multiplier value to the leading constraint for button against the superview?

Comment: You can give it centerX , with widthConstraint(give it a multiplier 0.5 to take 0.5 screen width) and a y constraint (top / bottom / centerY)